# How to include bootstrap mixins in a Angular2 webpack starter kit

Tags: angular, webpack, ng2-bootstrap

From the base webpack-starter for angular2, I have added in ng2-boostrap by simply including in the index.html:

```
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in my app.module.ts I added a:

```
import { AlertModule, DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

And then I see a nice Datepicker by adding a html snippet of

```
    <alert type="info">Hello from ng2-bootstrap  {{ date.toDateString() }}</alert>
<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
  <datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" showWeeks="true"></datepicker>
</div>
```

to my home.component.html.  And all seems great.

But then I created another component, all is good until I attempt to add a bit more scss of:

```
    .btn-facebook {
      @include button-variant($btnText, $btnFacebookBackgroundHighlight, $btnFacebookBackgroundHighlight);
    }
    .btn-twitter {
      @include button-variant($btnText, $btnTwitterBackground, $btnTwitterBackgroundHighlight);
    }
    .btn-google-plus {
      @include button-variant($btnText, $btnGooglePlusBackground, $btnGooglePlusBackgroundHighlight);
    }
    .btn-github {
      @include button-variant($btnTextAlt, $btnGithubBackground, $btnGithubBackgroundHighlight);
    }
```

Immediately I see:

```
Module build failed: 
@include button-variant($btnText, $btnFacebookBackgroundHighlight, $btnFacebookBackgroundHighlight);
      ^
  No mixin named button-variant
```

Being bring new to webpack and angular2, I am a bit clueless how to add these mixins to the build.  You help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use bootstrap mixins inside your `.scss` files:

1. You need to have bootstrap installed.

```
npm install bootstrap
```

2. You need to include the mixins file in your `.scss` file. Inside your `.scss` file:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables'
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_utilities'
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_buttons';
    
@include button-variant(); // use it
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  In the end I needed a bit more:
`@import '~bootstrap/scss/_mixins';
 @import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables';
 @import '~bootstrap/scss/_utilities';`